# @Html.ActionLink not wotking at all

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a weird problem with `@Html.ActionLink`: it doesn't do anything. It doesn't go to the controller or load the view. I have a project with a menu. From the menu I want to redirect to another view. When I use `@Html.ActionLink("Avioane", "Index", "Avioane", null, null)` it doesn't go to controller.

```
public class AvioaneController : Controller
{

     // [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          //var db = new Curse_AerieneEntities();
          //List<Avioane> avs = db.Avioane.Where(z => z.Disponibil).ToList();
          //return View(avs);
          return View();
     }
};
```

When I use `@Ajax.ActionLink("Avioane", "Index", "Avioane", new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod = "GET"})` and set `[HTTPGet]` on the controller, it goes to the view but doesn't load the view into the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If i write the url that needs to load the view it works, and when I hover to the menu Avioane I see the url in the buttom , left corner, it's right

Comment: `AJAX` doesn't work the way you imagine. Trough `AJAX` you are not getting a whole new page (you actually can, but it's not that straightforward). Your "classic" `ActionLink` should work and you should hit the action. Have you made any changes to your routes? The problem might be there.

Comment: My routeConfig is  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ); .. I use the same route like in other project that wotks.. I don't understand what the problem might be

Comment: Check the generated URL of the action link `@Html.ActionLink("Avioane", "Index", "Avioane")`.

Comment: It doesn't work... I've try different thinks and nothing's working.. I have no idea what to do or where I need to modify

Comment: Could you please post the HTML of the generated link?

Comment: I have no ideea what was wrong, but I created a new project and now it's working .. Thank's a lot. I appreciate your help